# How to pass parameters in crystal report using SQL command database Expert

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I want to generate report by selecting the date from ~ To and want to pass those value to variable x and y written at the end of the query

```
SELECT accounts.invoice, tempClient.name, tempClient.businessName,
tempClient.contactNumber,accounts.total, accounts.remaining
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN tempClient
ON accounts.clientCode = tempClient.id where accounts.[dateTime] between ?x and ?y
```

Like

[image: Like This and try to save]

But it gives me the error

saying

[image: Please Help Thanks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that "Parameter List" box that is empty to the right of your SQL Command? You want to create your parameters there. Also, when you reference them you want to use curly brackets to do it: `{?x}`

Comment: Thanks Buddy ... 
 It Worked . . . !